# MySQL - How can i remove specific part of a string?

Tags: html, mysql, iframe

I have some html embed codes inside my database. I want to remove all the height and width values from them. As their values are not the same i can't use "REPLACE" method. Embed codes are like `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="***" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`.

Are there any methods can replace 'width="{any value}"' with "" (emptiness)

Comment: have you looked up REG EX methods like 'width=(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1' http://regexr.com/3gnn1

Comment: Yes, I looked but I couldn't do. I tried to extract SQL file and replace with notepad++ but I failed again. Can anyone tell me which regex I should use to replace all the height and width from this SQL file with notepad++? Records are like this: "<iframe width=\"853\" height=\"480\" src=\"xxx" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" 
Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Lp878KG.png
I tried a hundred of combinations to get it work but it didn't. Here is a photo of some of what I tried: http://i.imgur.com/ktTjZXi.png

Comment: if you're using notepad or an editor then looking like they have the same value could you not simply do a find and replace, within your editor find  width=\"853\" replace all with  width="" etc

Comment: The thing that prevents me from using that simple method is, as i mentioned before, their scales are not the same. Some of them 853, some of them 600 etc. So i cannot use that method. I tried that before.